# Select a class on next div

Tags: jquery

Below is the span `product_qty` I want to select, but my code does not work.

```
<div class="pull-left">
    <div class="update-product">
       <a title="Plus This" href="#" onclick="addtoCart(531,530 ,1)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>

<span class="pull-left">
   <span class="product_qty"></span>
</span>
```

I am clicking on anchor button in `update-product` div And the function works as AJAX and then I want to select `product_qty` and update its HTML. I tried this:

```
$(this).closest('.pull-left').next().find('.product_qty').html(data.quantity);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your full code. Assuming you're running that jQuery code within a global scope `addtoCart()` function `this` will refer to the window, not the clicked element. If so, use an unobtrusive event handler instead. Also, where is `data` defined?

Comment: So if you are using `this` in your ajax function, it is not your `update-product` anymore. What you need to do is to use your code selecting the `.pull-left` outside of an ajax and save it to some variable which you can use later.

Comment: Please add a code snippet or example to see exactly what is happening, not having it can lead to the answer being closed. I am pretty sure that you want an answer for this question.

Comment: @Jai Why would you use `.parent()` after `.closest()` here?

Comment: @j08691 ah!!! question is been edited. i saw an extra closing of div.

Comment: @T.Bragg Here is full specification :  http://prntscr.com/dizqyl http://prntscr.com/dizr8m

Comment: Cache the jquery object outside of the ajax function `var $prodQty = ...` and then use the variable inside of the ajax complete function `$prodQty.html(data.quantity)`.

Comment: `$("span.pull-left>span.product-qty").html()`

Comment: i have added two pictures for clear idea

Comment: You are still not posting the entire javascript function.

Comment: Is there the possibility that more than one product is on the page at the same time?  If so then you are going to need to redo some thing in order ti differentiate between them.  Give them a unique ID or pass the `this` in to the onclick function.

Comment: @nurdyguy yes there may be more than one product.

Comment: @MusaMuaz Since there is more than one product, I'd recommend using jquery `.on('click',....)` bindings instead of onclick functions.  Both ways are possible but the `.on('click',...)` binding will work a little better with a `var myVar = $(this)` style of programming.  If you do want to stick with onclick function (and there is nothing wrong with that) then you either need to pass an identifier specific to that DOM element or pass the `this` pointer in the function.

Comment: @nurdyguy it easier for me by `onclick` because insite the `removeFromCart()` function i need to echo `hash, r_id, qty` by php

Comment: Here is a fiddle with both a very simple example of both options.  https://jsfiddle.net/8hmLc7rv/3/

Comment: @MusaMuaz You could store/echo those values in data attributes and pick them up in the `on.('click',...)` binding.  Like I said, either works, just trying to give you options/ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `$(this).closest('.pull-left')..` inside the success callback function of your AJAX call, which means `this` isn't referring to what you think it is (i.e. the anchor tag). The function will have a different 'context' when it's called.

You can either:

- Refer to your span explicitly: e.g. `$('.pull-left .product_qty')`, or
- As some have already mentioned in the comments, you can define and assign a variable just before you initiate your AJAX call and store a reference to that anchor tag. Example below

if you're doing with an `onclick` attribute, then you could pass the element to the function:

`<a onclick="removeFromCart(this, 'ABCDEFXYZ', 123, 1)">Remove</a>`

and

```
function removeFromCart(elem, hash, r_id, qty) {
    var anchor = $(elem);
    ... 
}
```

or it will be easier if you bind with `jQuery` like

`$('a.remove').on('click', removeFromCart)` and you won't need the `elem` argument in the function definition

Comment: There might be more products than one. `var anchor = $(this);` also not works : http://prntscr.com/dizzp6

Comment: how have you bound your event handler to the anchor? are you using `onclick` or `jQuery` binding like `$('a').on('click', removeFromCart)`? please see my edition to the answer

Comment: its `onclick` - `<a title="Plus This" href="#" onclick="addtoCart(531,530 ,1)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>`

Comment: then you will need to pass the element to the function call. `onclick=addToCart(this, 531,530, 1)"` and then in your function `addToCart(elem, id, another_id, qty) { var anchor = $(elem) }`

Comment: it results into `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)`

Comment: what does your code look like now? See my edits please